# Design pattern for handling a server response

Tags: objective-c, oop, design-patterns

I've an observer pattern on the UI that checks what's the status of an object that handles a server connection that's trying to update a certain field on a database.

The UI's update method receives an object containing data pairs containing the information of what's happening with the connection. The problem is that I'm getting tangled with a lot of ifs checking for different possibilities.

```
- (void) update:(Bundle *)arg
{
    if ([[arg getData:@"updatee"] isEqualToString:@"email"]){
        UITableViewCell *emailCell = [[self tableView] cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
        if ([[arg getData:@"connecting"] isEqualToString:@"true"]) {
            //Email is being posted
            [_emailLabel_email setText:@"Connecting..."];
            [_emailLabel_set setHidden:YES];
            emailCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
            [_emailActivityIndicator startAnimating];
        }else{
            if ([[arg getData:@"succesfull"] isEqualToString: @"false"])
                //Email was posted unsuccesfully
                [[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Taken Email Address"
                                    message:@"The email address that you entered is already in use, please double check it"
                                   delegate:nil
                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                          otherButtonTitles:nil] show];
            else{
                //Email was posted succesfully.
                [_emailLabel_set setText:@"Change"];

            }
            [_emailActivityIndicator stopAnimating];
            [_emailLabel_email setText:[mng getEmail]];
            [_emailLabel_set setHidden:NO];
            emailCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
        }
    }

 //Password cases
}
}
```

As the server responds with a string I'm finding difficult to avoid this spaggetti of code.

Which would be the smarter object to send on the update method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could keep the data how it is and put all of the values you expect for `[arg getData:@"updatee"]` as the keys in a dictionary. The values would be the string representation of method selectors, where each of the methods handles one of the cases in your current `if` statement. Now your `update:` method just gets the selector string from the dictionary, converts it to a real selector (`NSSelectorFromString`) and calls the method (passing the `arg` as a parameter, all methods used here must have matching parameter listing). If you receive an unexpected update type nothing would happen so you should log / assert that. If you get an exception while translating the selector you probably have a typo (good candidate for a test which executes all of the methods in the configuration).

Of course you could basically do the same thing with all the methods and a dirty big if / else statement.